# How to write a simple test case in react for below Header component? I am new to react

Tags: reactjs

I am a learner, This is sample Header component how to write jest test cases for this component.

```
import React from "react";
import './styles/Header.css';

const Header = () => <header className="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-md-between py-3 mb-4 header-border">
        <h5 className="header-title">Header Component</h5>
        <ul className="nav col-12 col-md-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
            <li><a href="#" className="nav-link px-2 link-secondary">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" className="nav-link px-2 link-dark">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" className="nav-link px-2 link-dark">Gallary</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" className="nav-link px-2 link-dark">FAQs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" className="nav-link px-2 link-dark">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form className="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"/>
        </form>
    </header>

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use `react-test-renderer` package to make a snapshot and test if your component renders properly. Usually you'd also test the functions of a component, but since you don't have any here, you can test for the presence of particular html elements.